# thread_local seems broken on Mac OSX 10.7.2 under gcc 4.9.1

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, c++11, thread-local-storage

this is my first time here...
I'm trying to uses multithreaded C++ code.
I'm on a Mac OSX 10.7.2.
Because the OS and compiler are so old and don't support c++11,
I followed the instructions here
   https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/06/11/compiling-gcc-mac-os-x/
I seem to have a working gcc 4.9.1, but then I tried doing some
multi-threading.

```
#include <thread>

using namespace std;



class X {
public:
   char *p;

   X() : p(0) { }
   ~X() { if (p) delete[] p; }
   void set(int n) { p = new char[n]; }
};


void task()
{
   static thread_local X x;
   x.set(8*23);
}

int main()
{
   thread t1(task);
   thread t2(task);
   thread t3(task);
   thread t4(task);
   thread t5(task);

   t1.join();
   t2.join();
   t3.join();
   t4.join();
   t5.join();
}
```

Well, if I compile this as

```
/usr/gcc-4.9.1/bin/g++-4.9.1 -g -std=c++11 simple.c
```

I get errors like this:

a.out(50392,0x100605000) malloc: *** error for object 0x137fe130400db0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Illegal instruction: 4

a.out(50405,0x102a70000) malloc: *** error for object 0x137fcf22500060: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Illegal instruction: 4

I tried adding -pthread and -lpthread as command-line options, but that didn't help.
I added print statement too, which revealed that the addresses in the error messages were the addresses of the static local objects themselves.

Maybe I'm trying to run this in an environment that is just too out of date.
Or maybe the right runtime is not getting linked in.
I'm not sure if anyone out there can help...maybe I just need to get access to 
a more up-to-date system.

Thanks!!